# DateTime.ParseExact for "dMMyyHHmmss" format not working (c#)

Tags: c#, date, datetime, date-parsing

I have dates comming in a log file with the following format: "dMMyyHHmmss".

As I want to throw an exception if the format found is not exactly that one, I'm using DateTime.ParseExact. The thing is that I'm getting a FormatException with the following message:

> 'String '.....' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The code to emulate this is:

```
var format = "dMMyyHHmmss";

var date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
var strDate = date.ToString(format);
date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Any thoughts why I can't use that format?

Comment: Its pretty obvious isnt it?  If you would have used the debugger you would see that 
 the `srtDate` variable is: `"10118010101"`.  Using `dMM` means a single digit day and a double digit (padded) month, so is it `10/11`? or `1/01`?  Its ambiguous, this is why you need delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the format somewhat ambiguous to the LL parser.

The string you got is `10118010101`

The parser reads `1` and goes like, ok its a `1` for `d`
Then it reads `0` and its confused, should it be `10` for `d` or should it be `1` for `d` and `01` for `MM`?

You can make the parser happy if you add a delimiter in between or use `dd` instead of `d` to make the grammar unambiguous

Comment: Yep, just tested this. It works fine when you add space between the parts.